# C# TreeView - BackColor для всех Node (перекрасить все ветки в дереве)

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста каким наиболее удобным способом можно перекрасить все ноды в дереве TreeView. Я делаю поиск с подсвечиванием результатов, но повторный поиск должен сбрасывать подсвечивание(backColor yellow) нодов, а именно перекрашивать в белый цвет. Подобное решение не спасает

```
        foreach (TreeNode oSubNode in oMainNode.Nodes)
            {
                oSubNode.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Классика - рекурсивный обход:

```
void TraverseNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.BackColor = Color.Black;
        TraverseNode(node.Nodes);
    }
}
```

Вызываете этот метод в нужном месте:

```
TraverseNode(treeView.Nodes);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо=)

Comment: А существует ли другой способ обхода дерева (нерекурсивный)? Вопрос чисто ради интереса.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko дерево - рекурсивная структура, поэтому и обходить придется рекурсивно. В общем случае не существует. Но если вы реализовали дерево на основе непрерывного массива (в ячейках - структуры, ссылка на вершину - индекс в массиве), то можно сделать не рекурсивный проход по массиву вершин. Но я такую реализацию дерева пока встречал только в учебных задачках.