# Функция типа void

Tags: c#, функции, рекурсия

Может ли быть рекурсивной функция типа void?

Comment: Да, конечно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663409/184217

Comment: `void Foo() => Foo();` Где используется? Для обхода по дереву вполне сгодится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция типа `void` -это функция, которая не возвращает значения, вот и все.

Рекурсия - это вызов функцией себя же, и с каждым разом на определенном этапе

То, что функция является `void` , еще не забирает у нее всех остальных свойств , присущих функциям, поэтому ответ - **Да, может**

Comment: Метод - это **функция**, которая находится в классе. Так, как C#, это ООП язык, создать функцию за пределами класса здесь невозможно. От сюда делаем вывод, что в C# слово **функция** не совсем правильное (хоть и обозначает тот же метод), правильней говорить **метод**. Именно "функция", как по мне, больше подходит под [Func<TResult>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) и то это не совсем правильное понятие. Так как теперь думаете, правильная ли будет метка [функции] у данного вопроса?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Я согласен с тем, что метка неправильная, должна быть метка "метод" или "процедура", но немного не согласен с приведенными вами аргументами. Все же главной характеристикой функции является наличие возвращаемого значения, поэтому фраза "функция типа `void`" сама по себе неверная. В языках, в которых доступны глобальные функции, следует различать функции и методы-функции: функции самодостаточны, методы-функции являются членами класса и могут использовать его данные. В C# функция и метод-функция являются синонимами

Answer (score 0):

Вы, наверное, прекращаете рекурсию снаружи? Я же обычно в самой рекурсивной функции. Вернуть значение, если оно требуются снаружи, а это не обязательно, проще всего через аргумент типа out, в C# можно ещё ref, в С++ в содержимом по переданному указателю (как в WinAPI).

Answer (score 0):

Я попробую дать обьяснение без слов в примере:

```
Factorial(10,0,1);

public void Factorial(int max, ref int number, ref int value)
{
    number++;

    if(number>=max)
        return;

    value*=number;

    Factorial(max, number, value);
}
```

код писал из головы не проверяя, так что могли закрастся ошибки.

Но условие выполнено -- метод возвращает void. :)

как видишь, все быть может.